# Why Array doesn't work in console?

Tags: javascript

```
var animel = new Array();

animel[0] = 'cat';
animel[1] = 'dog';
animel[2] = 'horse';
animel[3] = 'cow';
animel[4] = 'elephant';
animel[5] = 'tiger';
animel[6] = 'lion';
animel[7] = 'fish';

for (var i = 0; animel.length > i; i++) {
    setTimeout( function () {

        console.log(animel[i]);

    }, 2000);

}
```

When I execute this code in console, it logs `undefined` instead of the name of elements. What am I doing wrong in this?

Comment: I don't want to edit your post for nothing, but it's **animal**. The rest of the post is spot on :)

Comment: animel[8] will always be undefined, the counter `i` has already been incremented when the settimeout trigger.

Comment: The misspelling of `animal` in this and *all* the answers is really bothering me >.<  /OCD

Comment: A variable is a variable dude.... There's nothing called misspelling, only errors ;)

Answer (score 3):

A very common problem: the callback is executed asynchronously, but uses the last set value of `i`. The chain of events is:

- your loop sets a number of timeouts
- the loop ends, `i` has the value `8`
- the timeouts fire, and execute `console.log(animel[i])`, where `i` is `8`

To avoid that you need to break the closure connection to `i`:

```
setTimeout((function (index) {
    return function () { console.log(animel[index]); }
})(i), 2000);
```

Comment: wow... such code... so brackets... much closure...

Comment: (I (think) I was (a (Lisp ((((developer)) in a) former) life))).

Answer (score 2):

The functions inside the `setTimeout` are referencing the same `i` value.  So for each one, `i` is `8`.

You need to create a closure to "capture" the `i` values.

```
var createFunc = function(i){
    return function(){
        console.log(animel[i]);
    };
};
for (var i = 0; animel.length > i; i++) {
    setTimeout(createFunc(i), 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the array, the problem is how your closing over the variable `i`.

By the time the functions execute (2 seconds after the loops completes) `i` has been incremented beyond the bounds of `animel`. The easy solution is to provide the current value of `i` to `setTimeout` and receive it as a parameter in the function, like this:

```
for (var i = 0; animel.length > i; i++) {
    setTimeout(function (i) {
        console.log(animel[i]);
    }, 2000, i);
}
```

If you need to support this syntax on IE < 9, the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) provides several polyfill techniques.

Comment: Why are you passing `i` to `setTimeout`?  What will that do?

Comment: @RocketHazmat [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) accepts parameters to pass to the function when it executes.

Comment: Not a solution compatible will browsers though, notably IE < 9.

Comment: Do browsers actually support this?  I've never seen that syntax before.

Comment: @RocketHazmat It's supported by modern browsers and standardized in [HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers).

Comment: Oh, ok cool.  I guess it might need to be polyfilled in older browsers, though?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Correct, the MDN article provides several techniques, but they are somewhat complex, and given that there are other solid answers on this question describing backward compatible solutions, I chose not to include them.

Comment: I dunno, I like this syntax better! :-D

Answer (score 1):

This is a JS enclosure candidate. The value of `i` used in the `setTimeout` scope isn't the one you think at the time it is used. To force the actual value of `i` to be used when the timeout happens, you can use enclosure around it in a way that it will use `i` as a constant rather than an iterator.

```
for (var i = 0; i<animel.length; i++) {
    (function(x){
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(animel[x]);
        }, 500);
    })(i);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DeSP3/)

Answer (score 0):

You're wrapping it in a setTimeout function which is a non-blocking operation. By the time the loop has completed, i has been incremented to a value which breaks the loop and would be beyond the bounds of the array.